# Variable definiton causes wordpress to ignore layout/style

Tags: php, html

More of a comprehension question than coding help, I hope that's okay.

I tried to add the following line of code to my website (wordpress-based):

```
<?php $date = date_create(get_post_meta($id, 'date')[0]); ?>
```

Where get_post_meta() returns a string containing a date in the format YYYY-mm-dd. When I add it, half the page layout gets thrown out and the page doesn't take the full window with anymore, but instead just becomes about the size of the stackoverflow question form.

So my question is why does this line have any effect at all on the website? This should be purely background work, right? Even if it were placed within an html-element like a div (which is currently the case), it should not have any effect. Why am I experiencing this?

Comment: Have you checked the generated HTML (right click on the page and click on "view source"). Is there any error message or similar that messes up the layout or does the generated code look identical with or without that line? Where does `$id` come from? And are you sure that this will always return an array with the numeric index `0`?

Comment: The id is the post_id extrated earlier in the code, I already tested output and type of the get_meta_data-function and it works properly. As for the source code, it's a massive wall of code, but at least the div in question looks exactly the same

Comment: Unless it outputs something (an error/warning or similar), I don't really see how it would change the view. Do a full comparison of the output with or without that code snippet. We don't really have much to go on here.

Comment: fixed it by not defining the variable at all and simply doing everything in one line, i.e. `echo date_format(date_create(get_post_meta($id, 'date')[0]), 'd.m.Y');`